# What is the exact meaning of "attitude", does it include translational movement?

Tags: flight-controls, attitude

Reading documentation it is clear to me that "attitude" means the study of orientation of a body. However sometimes it seems to be used loosely for the motion tracking of a body (both translational and rotational, not rotational only).

Is it a mistake or a common abuse of language?

Comment: Attitude defines the logitudional axis of the plane in relation to the local vertical. What you are refering to is the Flight Path Vector, which is a the result of alle forces acting on the plane.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, attitude is *orientation* in space and it excludes translation.

Object orientation in space can be defined using multiple systems. The one used in aviation uses three angles:

- heading or yaw (around the yaw axis)
- pitch (around the lateral axis)
- roll or bank (around the longitudinal axis).

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://boltent.ca/flight/lessons/aeronautics/tutorial/motion.html).</sup>

Attitude is usually understood as orientation relative to the horizontal plane, that is only two angles:

- pitch
- roll/bank.

In the common definition heading is not taken into account. For example, in no wind condition, "level flight" is usually obtained by maintaining a constant attitude, that is constant pitch and roll angles. We'll find this sense in the expression [flying by attitude](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Aircraft_piloting/Attitude_flying), nose-up attitude or [unusual attitude](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Recovery_from_Unusual_Aircraft_Attitudes).

Attitude is visualized using an [attitude indicator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBURJ-mrb5E) (aka artificial horizon):

[image]
<sup>Attitude indicator, indicating 5° right roll and 10° down pitch</sup>

In some applications attitude may include heading as well, and thus becomes a synonym for *orientation* in space using the three angles:

- heading/yaw
- pitch
- roll/bank.

This use is more often found in [flight dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics_(fixed-wing_aircraft)) and astronautics than in aviation. In this sense attitude and speed help determine the [velocity vector](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/67211/angle-of-attack-from-velocity-vector). More on that in [attitude reference frames](https://ai-solutions.com/_freeflyeruniversityguide/attitude_reference_frames.htm).

Heading reference must be specified. In aviation heading reference can be geographic or magnetic North and has its own instrument, the [horizontal situation indicator](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/inpages/rcallendgelec2.php) or directional gyro (or the compass as a backup instrument):

[image]
<sup>Directional gyro, indicating a heading of 113°. [Source](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/inpages/rcallendgelec2.php)</sup>

The three angles can be combined into a single instrument, this is often the case for head up displays:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.flyrealhuds.com/products/business-jet-huds/).</sup>

3-angles attitude can be quantified as a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) or a matrix of angles, usually [Euler's angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) (actually Tait–Bryan's angles).

It can be visualized using a spherical attitude indicator (more at [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32078/is-flight-director-attitude-indicator-an-inside-joke-about-flight-directors)):

[image]
<sup>Orbiter attitude indicator, [source](http://www.space1.com/Artifacts/Artifacts_FOR_SALE/FS__Shuttle_Sim_Avionics/FS__Shuttle_Sim_ADI/FS_shuttle_sim_ADI_FDAI_front.jpg)</sup>